# Referencing the Closest Table Element Near the Image HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get access to the nearest table element from the Image HTML Element. I used siblings but it returns multiple tables since there are other tables at the same DOM level. I can access it using $(this).next().next() syntax but I do not want to do that.

Here is the screenshot. I am trying to access

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to reference a specific table?  Or does the table identity change dynamically as the page is refreshed or otherwise altered?

Comment: I would not call it specific table. It is table closest sibling to the IMG tag. Basically I am asking how to get a reference to the closest sibling.

Comment: Can you enhance the `img` tag with an id ? Would you chose a preceding `table` sibling if it were closer ?

Comment: The table element in your picture has an id attribute blocked out.  You can make a reference to the image by id, and then call the adjacent table by id. But if the table changes id, or a different object occurs/replaces it ... that is another problem.

Comment: The id of the table is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery statement will do the trick:

```
$("img").nextUntil("table").last().next();
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are elements between the table and the image which are also returned.

Comment: Solution corrected. Sorry for the mistake and thank you for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep iterating `nextElementSibling` until you find a `table` element:

```js
// `img` is a reference to the image element
var table = img;
while(
    (table = table.nextElementSibling)
    && table.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'table'
);
// Use `table` here. It will be `null` if no table is found
```